# Touch screen control?

Tags: release-freya

I have an Asus F550C laptop with touchscreen. The system recognizes when touch and it's like I was using the mouse(one click) but I can't scroll nor double-click. Is there any driver to make it work perfect or something like that? (The touchscreen works perfect in Win 10, with scrolling, double-clicking...)